# Derivative of Survival Function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to get through statistical survival analysis - sadly I only have high school math. I have the following equation:

$ S(t) = Pr\{T ≥ t\} = 1−F(t) = \int_t^\infty f(x) dx$

$f(x)$ is the probability density function. $F(t)$ is the cumulative distribution function, $S(t)$ is the survival function.

Apparently the derivative of $S(t)$ is $-f(t)$. I can't work out how to get that from the function above. Does the fact that $ F(t) = \int_0^t f(x) dx$ have anything to do with it? Or can it be worked out from the last equation?

Thanks for helping,

Steph

Comment: Yes, Fundamental Theorems of Calculus

Answer (score 1):

$$ S(t) = 1−F(t) = 1-\int_0^t f(x)dx$$

$$\frac{dS(t)}{dt}=0-\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t f(x)dx$$

The last part by the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) is exactly $f(t)$.

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t f(x)dx=f(t)$$

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something basic. (Didn't realise *how* basic!)

Comment: @Steph you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Just take the derivative of what you have before your last equality:
$$
\frac{d S(t)}{d t}=\frac{d}{dt}(1-F(t))=-\frac{d}{dt}F(t)=-f(t).
$$